# Use vim as an ide for javascript development?

Tags: javascript, vim, vim-plugin, vim-syntax-highlighting

I'm looking on trying out VIM for an IDE of some sort, I've installed [vimrc](https://github.com/amix/vimrc) for the most part it looks pretty decent.

What I'm missing is linting configuration for syntax errors and what not, some sort of intellisense (which I think vim-javascript does).

From what I've read, [vim-pathogen](https://github.com/tpope/vim-pathogen) is the way to install vim specific plugins.

I've followed the documentation in vim-javascript on how to install using pathogen. I notice after installing that I see text colors differently but I still don't get autocomplete of any sort.

I tried adding the configurations to my .vimrc file but I don't think I'm doing it right.

Here's what it looks like:

```
set runtimepath+=~/.vim_runtime

 execute pathogen#infect()
 source ~/.vim_runtime/vimrcs/basic.vim
 source ~/.vim_runtime/vimrcs/filetypes.vim
 source ~/.vim_runtime/vimrcs/plugins_config.vim
 source ~/.vim_runtime/vimrcs/extended.vim
 let g:javascript_plugin_jsdoc = 1
 let g:javascript_plugin_ngdoc = 1
 let g:javascript_plugin_flow = 1
 set foldmethod=syntax

 try
 source ~/.vim_runtime/my_configs.vim
 catch
 endtry
```

Comment: Have you heard of [spf-13](https://github.com/spf13/spf13-vim)?  I found it to be a nice starter for getting vim setup.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First mistake: considering Vim as an IDE.

Second mistake: using someone else's setup.

Third mistake: thinking you can get away without learning Vim.

Anyway…

- There's no such thing as `~/.vim_runtime`. Your user-level runtime directory is `~/.vim`.
- Pathogen is not a way to "install" plugins. It's a way to "enable" plugins. There are many plugins for installing plugins (which doesn't really make any sense), and you can simply install them manually, which is a lot easier than random bloggers would like you to think.
- "Syntax errors and what not" is done via `:help make`. Read it (and the related sections) instead of installing pointess plugins.
- "some sort of intellisense" is already built-in; it's called "omni-completion" and you can read about it in `:help ins-completion`. That plugin only provides an *alternative* syntax script (for syntax highlighting, mostly), an *alternative* indent script, and an *alternative* omni-completion script.
- Vim doesn't do autocompletion. It's totally unnecessary but if you *really* want it you can get it via some third-party plugins. You can find them in the "script" section of http://www.vim.org.
- That crappy over-engineered setup will get you nowhere. Remove it from your system and start again from scratch instead of abandoning control to random semi-ignorant gittards. The only thing you can achieve with distributions like these is never learning your tools properly.

Comment: I see, thanks for the clarification, I think I'll just install they VIM keystrokes for webstorm haha.

Comment: After 6 months of using Webstorm and IdeaVim, I have found it very unsatisfactory.  The biggest annoyance is that it randomly locks up in some wierd mode which can't be freed by <esc>.  This happens often enough that it disrupts fluent typing.  Cursor sometimes jumps in the middle of typing in Insert mode and the remainder of your text is inserted at some unexpected location.   Several other things.  I am fixing to switch back to editing in Vim and using scripts to do other IDE tasks.